# videojs not palying second video

Tags: jquery, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

I am using video js plugin in my mobile website, with one video everything works normally, but when I add the second video, the first one plays normal, but second one doesn't play at all, the videos are in two different pages, and they have different id's

any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you could post some code?